# Python Type hinting with curses

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.6, type-hinting, python-curses

I'm trying to figure out what to put in my type annotation at the top of this function.

I have the following trivial example:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()

    stdscr.addstr(2, 0, "What is the type of stdscr?")
    stdscr.addstr(5, 0, "It is: {}".format(type(stdscr)))

    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

This returns `<type '_curses.curses window'>`.  This doesn't seem like it will work with Type hinting as it has a space in it.  <strike>The expected result would be `WindowObject` listed in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.initscr).  I can't find a path to WindowObject in the curses module itself.</strike> EDIT:  The documentation is incorrect here.

How do I write main with accurate type annotation?

Comment: Just don't. `WindowObject` is a documentation error; the name of the window object type is undocumented and subject to change, and I don't think the window object type is even available as a module attribute.

Comment: Absolutamente  right @user2357112, type() method always tells the type object, no matter what

Comment: This is an odd case though.  I haven't seen a type() with a space in it.  How does the Typing library handle these?   I'm not saying I NEED to do it but this is a curious case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the curses module does not appear to be fully typed within typeshed. There was some [preliminary work done](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/789) a few months ago, but the Windows object has not been added yet. You can check the Python 3 'curses' stubs for yourself [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/curses/__init__.pyi) and [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/_curses.pyi).

Currently, the stubs default to typing `curses.wrapper` as:

```
def wrapper(func, *args, **kwds): ...
```

...which, in turn, is equivalent to:

```
def wrapper(func: Callable[..., Any], *args: Any, **kwds: Any): ...
```

So, that means that there really is no suitable type to assign to your `main` function's parameter at the moment, apart from `Any`.

That said, if you're up for it, you might be able to contribute some stubs to complete the `curses` module yourself! It doesn't seem like the [Window object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/curses.html#window-objects) is that terribly complex and should hopefully be relatively straightforward to type.

The main complication might be hammering out where exactly the 'Window' object should be imported from, if it doesn't exist within the curses module itself. You might perhaps want to stick the 'Windows' object within the `typing` module itself, just like [`typing.re.Pattern` and `typing.re.Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.re).

Comment: My pull request was just accepted.  
 Thank you @Michael0x2a https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/1271

Comment: This appears to have changed in Python 3.8 (maybe before that even?)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the type you spect is just not the real type of the object, the method type() always tells you the type correctly, so by sure the doc. is wrong.

Comment: This makes sense I've updated the question but the core question remains.

Answer (score 1):

Types can now be annotated via `curses.window`

```
def main( stdscr: curses.window ) -> Any:
```